# how to implement crud axios in react native using react native class component? (API)

Tags: react-native, api, axios

can anyone help me,

i am trying to make a simple CRUD using axios react native with class component,
to pass data from GET to Details data I succeeded, but when on the DETAIL page to retrieve only one data I had problems,
when I try console.log(dataTampung) / console.warn(dataTampung), the data array appears, but we want to display it instead of undefined.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import axios from 'axios'

export class DetailData extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        
        this.state = {
            dataTampung: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount (){
        this.getData(); 
    }
    
    getData = () => {
        axios.get('http:my_local_ip_endpoind/api.php?on=detail&id='+this.props.route.params.id)
        .then( response => {
            this. setState({
                dataTampung:response.data.data.result
            })
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { id } = this.props.route.params;
        const { dataTampung } = this.state;

        console.warn(dataTampung);
        return (
            <View>
                <Text> This ID  = {id} </Text>
                <Text> Title  = {`${dataTampung.title}`} </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default DetailData
```

And this is how it appears:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx36n.png)

Please help :(
I apologize in advance for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the array with a dot notation. First, access the specific index in the array in thing case `dataTampung[0]` which will give you the object, then you can access the title as `dataTampung[0].title`.

Comment: I think still the same, not working, instead I get an error = 
ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'dataTampung[0].title')

Comment: I think you will need to check if the array has a length before trying to access it.

Comment: yeahh, it's work.. when i try to give if else condition for array dataTampung..

thank alot.. :)